# Orchestration function: DrylocAdapter.cs not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-function-app

I am attempting to run our orchestration function app locally with Visual Studio 2019. The app keeps failing with the error: "DrylocAdapter.cs not found"[image: Screenshot]

I am not sure what the cause of this error is. There is no DrylocAdapter.cs file in this solution. Below is the function I was trying to trigger locally:

```
[FunctionName("EmailProductUpdates")]
    public async Task EmailProductUpdates([TimerTrigger("*/2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient client, ILogger logger)
    {
        // run every day at 9:15am
        logger.LogInformation("Starting function");
        try
        {
            await _productUpdateCommand.SendAllProductUpdateEmails();
            await _productUpdateCommand.CleanUpProductHistoryData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the call stack look like around that exception?

Comment: Are you using DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection in your project?

Comment: Is [Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019) enabled? That should stop it from trying to display source code that is coming from an external library.

Comment: It seems you didn't show the whole code. Where is `_productUpdateCommand`?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you also have a constructor (which you did not include in the shared code snippet) having a bunch of dependencies like `_productUpdateCommand` injected. The issue here is most likely because of missing DI registration (or some child dependency) at [Function startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) due to which there is exception raised which resolution. Again you missed to share that exception probably due to the overwhelming `DrylocAdapter.cs not found` error.

Now the `DrylocAdapter.cs not found` is most likely because you have [Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code) disabled in VS settings (Debugging -> General) which is trying to navigate to the internal source of Function DI (internally Function uses [DryIoC](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc)) when dependency resolution failed, but could not navigate to source due to missing symbols (most likely symbol server turned off in VS settings).

All in all, the root cause is in the first paragraph, second is just insights for the surface error.